# Slim template doesn't render markdown stored in a variable

Tags: markdown, slim-lang

I have data in a database that uses the markdown format.

I know that [slim template](https://github.com/slim-template/slim) can render markdown like so:

```
markdown:
  This is a paragraph!

  - This is list item #1
  - This is list item #2
```

Now I try to do this:

```
markdown:
  #{string_in_markdown_format}
```

But this simply puts the whole content of the string into a single `<p>` tag, and doesn't really convert the markdown stuff in the string itself:

Here is the content of `string_in_markdown_format`:

```
Für alle graphisch vermittelten Informationen müssen gleichwertige Text-Alternativen zur Verfügung gestellt werden. Dekorative Grafiken müssen vom Screenreader ignoriert werden können.

Die Grundregeln sind dabei:

- Informative Grafiken erfordern immer einen Alternativ-Text (alt-Attribut)
- Dekorative Grafiken erfordern ein leeres Alt-Attribut (alt=““), damit der Screenreader sie ignorieren kann
- Bei verlinkten Grafiken ist nicht der Bildinhalt zu beschreiben, sondern das Linkziel anzugeben. Diese Funktion kann aber vom Linktext übernommen werden, wenn die Grafik z.B. im gleichen `&lt;a&gt;`-Element eingebunden ist.
```

Here is the result:

```
<p>Für alle graphisch vermittelten Informationen müssen gleichwertige Text-Alternativen zur Verfügung gestellt werden. Dekorative Grafiken müssen vom Screenreader ignoriert werden können.

Die Grundregeln sind dabei:

- Informative Grafiken erfordern immer einen Alternativ-Text (alt-Attribut)
- Dekorative Grafiken erfordern ein leeres Alt-Attribut (alt=““), damit der Screenreader sie ignorieren kann
- Bei verlinkten Grafiken ist nicht der Bildinhalt zu beschreiben, sondern das Linkziel anzugeben. Diese Funktion kann aber vom Linktext übernommen werden, wenn die Grafik z.B. im gleichen `&lt;a&gt;`-Element eingebunden ist.</p>
```

Screenshot:
[image]

**Update**

At the time being I'm using the following ugly workaround:

```
- markdown = Redcarpet::Markdown.new(Redcarpet::Render::HTML)
= markdown.render(string_in_markdown_format).html_safe
```

Answer (score 4):

> Now I try to do this:
>
> ```
> markdown:
>   #{string_in_markdown_format}
> ```

This actually works as intended: The content of the `markdown:` filter is passed *without any further processing* into a Markdown parser. Markdown itself does not specify any string interpolation.

Now, your "ugly workaround" is almost what I'd recommend:

```ruby
# first define a helper (assumig Rails here):
module MarkdownHelper
  def markdown(text)
    rc = Redcarpet::Markdown.new(Redcarpet::Render::HTML)
    rc.render(text).html_safe
  end
end
```

Then, in your view, simply call that helper:

```
= markdown string_in_markdown_format
```

Comment: That's a bit sad. It would have felt much more intuitive if it worked the way I proposed. Thanks for your answer, though.

Comment: does redcarpet render sanitize?